# How to pass abstract method as reference?

Tags: c#, methods, abstract-class, pass-by-reference

I will admit, i am doing homework and i am stuck on this one question (Part A). How do i pass the notice method as reference to the railway signal ? Can't i just find out which class was called in the abstract constructor and then print the class name within the notify method? For example:

#### RailwayUser

```
private string className;

public RailwayUser()
{ 
    Type type = this.GetType();
    className = type.Name;
}

public void PrintClassName()
{
  Console.Writeline(className);
}
```

#### RailwaySignal Class

```
public void Notify()
{
    foreach(RailwayUser u in _watches)
    {
        u.PrintClassName();
        u.Notice(State)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: A typical [event handler delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) has two arguments. What are they (just look at the names)? Maybe you could copy that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of code / design is flawed, since what it does is `RailwayUser`, registers the object reference with the `_watchers` List in the `RailWaySignal` class, which in turn calls the public `Notice` method on each user when `Notify` is invoked, which is not how `Event Signaling` or `Function Pointer` works. In fact public `_watchers` is dangerous, as it can be cleared by any user, though that can be moderated using property access

**Code with Issue**

```
public void Notify()
{
    foreach(RailwayUser u in _watches)
    {
        u.PrintClassName();
        u.Notice(State)
    }
}
```

Following shall be the actual code using events and delegates:

**Correct Version**

Code Snippet Online - https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/uEc

```
void Main()
{
    List<RailwayUser> railwayUsers = new List<RailwayUser>();

    railwayUsers.Add(new RailwayUser());
    railwayUsers.Add(new RailwayUser());

    RailwayUser.TestNotification();
}

public enum Colour
{
    Red,
    Green,
    NoSignal
}

public class RailwaySignal
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public RailwaySignal(string railwaySignalName)
    {
        Name = railwaySignalName;
    }   

    // Delegate for handling event
    public delegate void RailwaySignalEventHandler(object source, Colour e);

    // Delagate object for handling event
    private RailwaySignalEventHandler _railwaySignalEvent;

    // Event Accessor
    public event RailwaySignalEventHandler RailwaySignalEvent
    {
        add
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                _railwaySignalEvent += value;
            }
        }

        remove
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                _railwaySignalEvent -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Invoke Event for subscribed clients
    private void Notify()
    {
        if (_railwaySignalEvent != null)
            _railwaySignalEvent.Invoke(this, Colour.Green);
    }

    // Test the Event Invocation
    public void TestEvent()
    {
        Notify();
    }
}

public class RailwayUser
{
    private static RailwaySignal railwaySignal { get; set;} = new RailwaySignal("Signal1");

    public RailwayUser()
    {
        railwaySignal.RailwaySignalEvent += this.Notice;        
    }

    public static void TestNotification()
    {
        railwaySignal.TestEvent();
    }

    public void Notice(object sender, Colour color)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine($"Notice Called, Colour is :: {color}, Sender is :: {((RailwaySignal)sender).Name}");
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Notice Called, Colour is :: Green, Sender is :: Signal1
Notice Called, Colour is :: Green, Sender is :: Signal1
```

**Important Details**

- Signature of the event is, `(object source, Colour e)` which helps in passing the relevant information across to the `RailwayUser` called, We now know the RailwaySignal triggering the notification to the RailwayUser and its Colour value
- Event / Delegate has same signature as called method (which is the basis of working of Delegate / function pointers)
- For simplification `RailwayUser` is a non abstract class
- Event is executed using `Notify()` method inside the `RailwaySignal`, we are calling it artificially using `TestNotification()` inside `RailwayUser` just for demo purpose, but ideally it shall be internally triggered and shall pass on current state like Colour
- Pre-defined delegates like `Func`, `Action` are quite often used for similar notification mechanism, They internally works using similar mechanism, though declaring an explicit `event` which is internally a `delegate` is a well defined pattern, especially for the Ui controls
- Standard events exposed by the .Net framework have the signature `object sender, EventArgs e`, where `EventArgs` can wrap all information from Event executor (RailwaySignal) to Event  receiver (RailwayUser)

Answer (score 1):

It seem like a Observer pattern.You can pass SubClass which inherit from `RailwayUser` object instance into `RailwaySignal` class

Your `RailwayUser` class need create `public abstract void Notice(Colour state)` method.

```
public abstract class RailwayUser
{
    private string className;

    public RailwayUser()
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        className = type.Name;
    }

    public void PrintClassName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(className);
    }

    public abstract void Notice(Colour state);
}
```

`Driver` class can inherit `RailwayUser` class then **override** Notice method.

```
public class Driver : RailwayUser
{
    public override void Notice(Colour state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Driver see the {state.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

There are

1. `List<RailwayUser> _watches` contain observable object
2. use `SubScript(RailwayUser user)` subscription user on `_watches` List.
3. RailwayUser `Notify()` to invoke all your observable Notify method.

look like this.

```
public class RailwaySignal
{

    private List<RailwayUser> _watches;

    public Colour Stata { get; set; }

    public RailwaySignal()
    {
        _watches = new List<RailwayUser>();
    }

    public void SubScript(RailwayUser user)
    {
        _watches.Add(user);
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        foreach (RailwayUser u in _watches)
        {
            u.PrintClassName();
            u.Notice(Stata);
        }
    }
}
```

sample:https://dotnetfiddle.net/GcdGMy

---

You can also use `event` to pass method into `RailwaySignal` then invoke `Notify` method.

```
public enum Colour
{
    Green,
    Red,
    Disable
}
public abstract class RailwayUser
{
    private string className;

    public RailwayUser()
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        className = type.Name;
    }

    public void PrintClassName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(className);
    }

    public abstract void Notice(Colour state);
}

public class Driver : RailwayUser
{
    public override void Notice(Colour state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Driver see the "+ state.ToString());
    }
}

public class Controller : RailwayUser
{
    public override void Notice(Colour state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Controller see the " + state.ToString());
    }
}


public class RailwaySignal
{
    public delegate void NoticeEvent(Colour state);

    public event NoticeEvent Notifys;
    public Colour Stata { get; set; }

    public void Notify()
    {
        if (Notifys != null)
        {
            Notifys(Stata);
        }
    }
}
```

use like this.

```
RailwaySignal railway = new RailwaySignal() { Stata = Colour.Green};

railway.Notifys += new Driver().Notice;
railway.Notifys += new Controller().Notice;

railway.Notify();
```

sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/GcdGMy

Comment: Please consider following changes to the code:

1. `public event NoticeEvent Notifys`, event shall never be public, it shall be accessed via property and shall be thread safe due to multiple subscriber accessing it. Also its dangerous, since any user can reset the event object to null, thus wiping out all other subscribers

2. `IObservable` pattern is better suited for across the network notification, which is used by messaging queues, for in process memory, event - delegate is always better suited